# Get in range without recursion in haskell

Tags: haskell, currying

I'm learning Haskell and am stuck this problem. I'm creating a function called getInRange that takes two ints and a list as parameters, v1, v2, and iL . Basically I want to traverse through the list, iL, and get the numbers in range from v1 and v2. I'm trying to use a high order function to do this problem, so no recursion. I am also new to currying and have attempted to try use it in my solution.  I have a helper function 'check' that would check if given value x, is in range of v1 and v2.  I try running my code, but I end up getting `error: parse error on input 'getInRange'`  Here is my code:

```
check v1 v2 z  = if (z > v1 && z < v2) then z

--getInRange
getInRange :: Ord a => a -> a-> [a] -> [a]
getInRange v1 v2 (x:xs) = foldr (check v1 v2) [] (x:xs)
```

As an example input and output,

```
getInrange 3 5 [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] 
= [4]
```

Comment: Hint: use `filter` instead of `foldr`.

Comment: @chepner so would I do something like: let x = filter (> v1) iL, then use filter again for v2? But at the same time, is filter a high order function?

Comment: Besides fixing your existing solution, always remember you could also use a `list comprehension` approach to generate the same results:
`getInRange v1 v2 iL = [x | x <- iL, x > v1, x < v2]`
That essentially means "take x from the list iL, but only when x > v1 and x < v2".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're getting a syntax error because you don't have an `else` for your `if`. In Haskell, this is always mandatory.

The normal way to filter elements from a list is the `filter` function, thus the rest of my answer will be split: one that uses `filter` (as is idiomatic), and one that uses `foldr`, even though that's unusual (in case you'd like to do it that way, either to learn or just for fun).

## `filter`

Since `filter` takes a filtering function of type `a -> Bool`, and your condition returns a `Bool`, you don't need an `if` at all, so change your `check` function to this:

```
check v1 v2 z  = z > v1 && z < v2
```

And then change your `getInRange` function to use `filter`:

```
getInRange :: Ord a => a -> a-> [a] -> [a]
getInRange v1 v2 = filter (check v1 v2) -- see below about your (x:xs)
```

## `foldr`

To use `foldr`, you need a folding function of type `a -> b -> b`, where `a` is the type of the list elements, and `b` is the type of the result. In this case, that comes out to `Ord a => a -> [a] -> [a]`. To make `check` work, it needs to append the element to the result it's building if your condition is true, and leave the result alone if not:

```
check v1 v2 z acc  = if (z > v1 && z < v2) then z:acc else acc
```

Or, cleaned up a bit:

```
check v1 v2 z acc =
  if z > v1 && z < v2
    then z:acc
    else acc
```

If you want, you can express the conditional using a guard instead of an `if` statement, which some people consider to be more idiomatic:

```
check v1 v2 z acc
  | z > v1 && z < v2 = z:acc
  | otherwise = acc
```

## Final note about both ways

You use `(x:xs)` to match the list. This means that your pattern match is incomplete, and your function is thus partial, and will fail at runtime if you call it with an empty list. To fix this, just change `(x:xs)` to a single variable (like `xs`) in both places, or just remove it entirely, since it's at the end of both the left and right side (this is called eta-reducing).

Comment: I took some liberties, including fixing the partial match earlier. If you disagree, feel free to revert.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it really me helped understand what I was doing wrong.